# How do I enable nis schema in apacheDS?

Tags: centos, ldap, apache-ds

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to enable the nis schema in apacheDS (I want to be able to use the posixGroup and posixAccount classes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. Change the m-disabled attribute to FALSE (this attribute is under ou=schema and then cn=nis). Restart Apache Directory Studio and refresh the classes. posixAccount and posixGroup shows up then.